# Counting substring, while loop

Tags: java, string

```
public class SubstringCount
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word longer than 4 characters, and press q to quit");
    int count = 0;


    while (scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a word longer than 4 characters, and press q to quit");
        String word = scan.next();

        if (word.substring(0,4).equals("Stir"))
        {
            count++;
            System.out.println("Enter a word longer than 4 characters, and press q to quit");
            scan.next();
        }

        else if (word.equals("q"))
        {
            System.out.println("You have " + count + ("words with 'Stir' in them"));
        }

        else if (!word.substring(0,4).equals("Stir")) 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a word longer than 4 characters, and press q to quit");
            scan.next();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here I need to print how many words entered by the user contain the substring 'Stir.' However I'm not sure how to get this to work, or if I've done any of it right in the first place!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Note that `String.substring(0,4).equals("Stir")` is equivalent to `String.startsWith("Stir")`

Comment: @assylias no, it's not! The first one can throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the line: `Enter a word longer than 4 characters, and press q to quit` will be printed twice on each iteration. Plus, you are using a wrong function to check if the string contains a sub-string. Some of your `if-else` statements needed to be changed. Here is a better version of your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class SubstringCount
    {
         public static void main(String[] args)
         { 
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.println("Enter a word longer than 4 characters, and press q to quit");
             int count = 0;
             while (scan.hasNextLine())
             {
                String word = scan.next();
                if (word.contains("Stir"))
                {
                  System.out.println("Enter a word longer than 4 characters, and press q to quit");
                  count++;
                }
                else if (word.equals("q"))
                {
                  System.out.println("You have " + count + ( "words with 'Stir' in them"));
                  System.out.println("Enter a word longer than 4 characters, and press q to quit");
                }   
                else
                {
                  System.out.println("Enter a word longer than 4 characters, and press q to quit");
                }
             } //end of while
        }      //end of main
    }          //end of class
```

Note that in this case you are stuck in an infinite while loop. In order to really "quit" when entering `q`, you should `break` and get out from the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `String.contains ("Stir")` instead of `String.substring(0,4).equals("Stir")`

As [javadoc for String.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) states, this method

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified
>   sequence of char values.

Answer (score 0):

`String.contains("Stir")`

will help in your case.